# Xboard Error - Perl

Tags: perl, chess

I am using Xboard 4.8.0 to implement a chess application with Perl programming language.

Unfortunately, I got following error after same movements:

*Illegal move "xxyy" from first machine*

Is this a bug of Xboard? When I googled it, I could not understand but it seems it is not related my Perl code, but related with Xboard.

If this is a bug at Xboard, is there a solution?

Comment: So, is "xxyy" a valid move? And is your program the "first machine"? Xboard has been used a lot for a long time, so it is unlikely not to work at all.

Comment: Yes, of course "xxyy"  is valid move. When I started program and Xboard is displayed, another program called 'Chess' was being opened too. I uninstaled it thinking that it caused this error but nothing changed. I do not know what is meant with the word "first machine".

Comment: Also, "xxyy" is not the coordinate I played. For example I am playing e3xf8, but error message says : Illegal move "b7xh3" from first machine

Answer (score 0):

I thought that it was Xboard error, but it is Perl code error at my program. This is a very common message people encounter and as I see from forums that people thinks it is Xboard error but it seems that there is no problem at Xboard, but at the code used to execute Xboard